# Insert string values with apostrophe into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have read through some of the related questions but I still don't understand. So I decided to post a question here. I have a query like below

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table (q1,q2,q3,q4....q25) VALUES ('".$_POST['Q1']."',
'".$_POST['Q2']."',
'".$_POST['Q3']."',
'".$_POST['Q4']."'.....)";

mysql_query($query);
```

The $_POST['Qx'] value is obtained from a survey where people are allowed to type in comments. Often people would like in **words like "don't, can't, doesn't ..."**. The apostrophe will cause the problem when inserting the data to the table.

I have read through some articles suggesting the method of

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Q1'])
```

But I have 25 questions, some of them even have sub-questions.. so I have around 70 data to input to the table.

Is there any good method that I can adopt to be able to pass apostrophes into MySQL table?

Comment: Use PDO, it's much easier. take a look at this [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: I can't believe this question is still being asked in 2012.

Comment: loop through the questions with mysql_real_escape_string applied over each question.It wld be better if you use mysqli,pdo rather than mysql which in no longer maintained by community

Comment: Matt: In all likelihood those questions will still be asked in 10 years, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol ;-)

Comment: @MattHumphrey Can you recommend me the best way to learn PHP/MYSQL in 2012?

Comment: @ChrisYeung Use a framework would be the best start.

Comment: @MattHumphrey I have taken a look at best 5 php framework in 2012. They are namely, Yiiframework, codeigniter, zend,cakephp, symfony. Which one would you all reccomend?

Comment: @ChrisYeung Personally I love [Fuel](http://fuelphp.com) as it is perfectly suited for >= PHP5.3. [This site](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a very good port of call when learning PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

edit: `so I have around 70 data to input to the table.`
70 is "nothing " for a for-loop ;-)

```
for($i=1; $i<71; $i++) {
  $params[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Q'.$i], $link);
}
```

But you might want to consider a [redesign of your database tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

---

You have to encode/escape the parameters. In case of the (deprecated) mysql extension that would be [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

```
$link = mysql_connect(...);
...
$query = sprintf(
    "
        INSERT INTO
            Table
            (q1,q2,q3,q4....q25)
        VALUES
            ('%s','%s' ...)
    ", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Q1'], $link),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Q2'], $link)
    ...
);

mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error($link));
```

but better use a supported extension like mysqli or [pdo](http://docs.php.net/pdo).
And take a look at [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).